# Html Agility Pack, couldn't SelectNodes

Tags: linq, xpath, html-agility-pack

Here's the HTML file, it's truncated due to the content size and contained with an "img" tag at the end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <title>The Waste Land</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wasteland.css" class="day" title="day"/> 
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wasteland-night.css" class="night" title="night"/>   
</head>
<body>
    <section epub:type="frontmatter" id="frontmatter">
        <section epub:type="titlepage" id="titlepage">
            <h1>The Waste Land</h1>
            <div class="aut">T.S. Eliot</div>
            <div epub:type="epigraph">              
            </div>
            <p epub:type="dedication">For Ezra Pound: <span xml:lang="it">il migliorfabbro</span></p>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section epub:type="bodymatter" id="bodymatter">
        <section id="ch1">
            <h2>I. THE BURIAL OF THE DEAD</h2>
                <div>Looking into the heart of light, the silence.</div>
                <div xml:lang="de" id="ln42">
                    <em>Od' und leer das Meer</em>.<a epub:type="noteref" class="noteref" href="#note-4">*</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="linegroup">
                <img src="www.href">The lady of situations.
                </img>
                <div>Here is the man with three staves, and here the Wheel,</div>
                <div>And here is the one-eyed merchant, and this card,</div>
                </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Here's my code

```
HtmlNodeCollection imgNodes= HTMLDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
```

or

```
 List<HtmlNode> imgNodes = HTMLDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name =="img").ToList();
```

Neither can retrieve any tags. What can i do?

Comment: The first one with //img works for me, it returns the img. What's your code?

Comment: Actually the full html code is [here](http://tny.cz/9b24f72f). and my code like this :   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HTMLDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                            HTMLDoc.Load(ContainerXml.Stream);
                                                       HtmlNode bodyNode = HTMLDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
                           HtmlNodeCollection imgNodes= HTMLDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img");   But it returns null :(

Comment: Oh I'm sorry would you please replace the SelectSingleNode with SelectNodes. I want to select all the img tags, I've just miss-typed it. Thank you sir

Comment: I did notice that your HTML has XML namespaces defined, though that shouldn't affect HAP and it's ability to read and query the document. What framework/version are your targeting? I'm able to find the node as-is as expected.

Comment: If I save the full html as a file and load it using HtmlDocument.Load, the SelectNodes('//img') does return one node. You must be doing something else, or you're not loading the same document.

Comment: my HAP version is 1.4.6.0, I'm developing a WP7.1 app. After restarted my computer, the problem is itself solved. I don't know how it went wrong. I would like to apologize for coming up with this. Thank you for your supports.